# Should javafx gui instantiation and gui handling code be unit tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx-8

I'm a little new to java.
I have a project that is 25% javafx GUI instantiation / GUI handling.

I'm attempting to reach project code coverage >80%, but my untested GUI code is pulling it down.
Do I need to test this code?

I've looked into using TestFx library, but struggling to find good teaching resources.